# How Can I write a trigger of DELETE for deleting any employee, as an error message.

Tags: database-design, trigger

The conditions are.

1. If the employee is not associated with any records and nothing to be printed and the employee should be deleted normally.
2. If the employee is associated with at least one record the total number of those records should be printed, and the employee should not be deleted.
3. If multiple employee are deleted as one operation and at least one of the employee is associated with a record then the total number of records for all the deleted employee should be printed and none of the employee should be deleted, including those with no records